# Outlook mail add-in detect client type

Tags: outlook, office365, outlook-addin, office365api, office-js

I'm developing an [Outlook Mail Add-in](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/outlook/outlook-add-ins) there is a requirement for me to make the add-in behave differently in the Desktop Outlook client and Web Client.

I was going throgh the [Outlook Add-in API documentation](https://dev.outlook.com/reference/add-ins/index.html) but I couldn't find a way to detect the client type. Can anyone tell me if this is possible and how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Office.context.mailbox.diagnostics.hostName](https://dev.outlook.com/reference/add-ins/Office.context.mailbox.diagnostics.html#hostName)